# 'Expecting a stackmap frame' error encountered during starting an OSGi bundle

Tags: osgi

I had an OSGi bundle (an Apache Sling Custom AuthenticationHandler) built successfully into a JAR file. When I installed the bundle jar into my final OSGi environment (Felix) and started the bundle, I got the following error in the log:

```
Error: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 13 in method com.fl.safe.authhandler.SafeAuthenticationHandler.unbindRepository(Lorg/apache/sling/jcr/api/SlingRepository;)V at offset 5) java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 13 in method com.fl.safe.authhandler.SafeAuthenticationHandler.unbindRepository(Lorg/apache/sling/jcr/api/SlingRepository;)V at offset 5
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    ...
```

What could have possibly gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a corrupt JAR file. `VerifyError` is thrown by the JVM when a class file is internally inconsistent or has a security problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the Bundle was compiled using Java 1.6 and deployed to an OSGi container environment of Java 1.7 was causing the specific error. For those who may run into the same problem, you can `file` command to figure out what version of java was used to compile and generate your .class files. For example,

```
% file XQueryUtil.class
XQueryUtil.class: compiled Java class data, version 49.0 (Java 1.5)
```